# download file whith powershell v 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I hope I am not out of OT I have a problem with powershell v2.0 with win 7 I am writing a dos batch file whose task, among other things, is to download a file. To do this I am using powershell 2.0 by win 7. I don't know this language and I can't go on anymore.

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://downloads.html/example.exe","C:\tmp\example.exe")}"
```

the error he gives me is the following

> ')' missing in the method call. In row: 1 car: 52
>
> - & {((New-Object System.Net.WebClient) .DownloadFile (<<<< https://downloads.ar
>   duino.cc/arduino-1.8.13-windows.exe,C:\tmp\arduino-1.8.12-windows.exe))}
>
>   - CategoryInfo: ParserError: (CloseParenToken: TokenId) [], Paren
>     tContainsErrorRecordException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId: MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
>     thanks

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is
`(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)`

I didn't run your code but it looks like you're missing a parentheses before ".download".

Comment: hi steezy, i corrected the command but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Not sure if you are still stuck on this, what specifically doesn't work? Are you getting the same result?